# jQuery safer form

Tags: jquery, security, captcha

I'm designing a registration form for a website, and was originally going to put a captcha on it to prevent spammers posting information to it remotely. But then I found this article about safer forms using jQuery: http://15daysofjquery.com/safer-contact-forms-without-captchas/11/

I was just wondering how this is working? If a spammer remotely accesses the form, will not the javascript add the hidden field to his form as well? Or will this only happen when the user loads the form in his browser...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most bots are quite primitive and don't recreate a browser's environment - they will just parse the HTML.

Comment: But that assumption was made back in 2006. Does it really still ring true in 2011?

Comment: @Antony I believe so. Though there are sophisticated bots that will recreate the browser.